# Quantum versus classical communication complexity

Tags: computational-complexity, quantum-mechanics, communication-complexity

> **Problem.** Is it true that any 2-party communication problem $f(x,y)$ of poly-logarithmic complexity in the quantum simultaneous message passing model ($Q''$) has complexity $n^{o(1)}$ (i.e., strongly sub-polynomial) in the classical 2-way communication model ($R$)?

(This problem was written 13.09.2018 by Dmitry Gavinsky from Prague on [page 57](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=2&page=57) of [Volume 2](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=2) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).